# In k$\cdot$p theory, how does one calculate the bulk inversion asymmetry coefficients given in table 6.3 in Winkler?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, semiconductor-physics, topological-insulators

In [k$\cdot$p theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C2%B7p_perturbation_theory), how does one calculate the bulk inversion asymmetry coefficients given in table 6.3 in Winkler?

Winkler's book on spin-orbit coupling effects is available [free online](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/QTTG/NOTES/SPINTRONICS/WINKLER=spin_orbit_coupling_effect_in_2d_electron_and_hole_systems.pdf).

In chapter 6 (section 6.2.1) he discusses BIA invariants and gives the formulas for computing them in Equation 6.2, while in table 6.3 he lists a few of them computed for some materials. He states that Band parameters were taken from Landolt-Bornstein which does indeed list the various energy gaps, and maybe the Kane parameter P.

My question is how does one compute these coefficients in table 6.3 for a different material? I have searched for weeks and tried to use equations 6.2, however I have not found one reference that lists the values of the other Kane parameters P' and Q, and therefore I cannot use them accurately. Winkler quotes Landolt-Bornstein as the reference for table 6.3, however in LB the values of P' and Q are never given, only energy gaps (E0, E0', Delta ... etc)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!